# Java Calculator Displaying Incorrect Results

Tags: java, swing, runtime-error, calculator

Having a bit of trouble with my program, it is displaying the wrong results and when you try to do the calculations for a single digit you will get a error. Program posted below, any help is appreciated.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Calc extends JFrame{
public static void main(String[] args){
    Calc myFrame = new Calc();
    myFrame.pack();
    myFrame.setTitle("Calculator");
    myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    myFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    myFrame.setVisible(true);
}//main


private JTextField jtfNum1, jtfNum2, jtfResult;
private JButton jbtAdd, jbtSub, jbtMul, jbtDiv, jbt1, jbt2, jbt3, jbt4, jbt5, jbt6, jbt7, jbt8, jbt9, jbt0, jbtDec, jbtC, jbtE, jbtClear;
double number1 = 0;
double number2 = 0;
double result = 0;
String display = "";
String display1 ="";
char oper = ('A');

public Calc(){
    JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
    p1.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,4));
    p1.add(jbt1 = new JButton("1"));
    p1.add(jbt2 = new JButton("2"));
    p1.add(jbt3 = new JButton("3"));
    p1.add(jbtAdd = new JButton("+"));
    p1.add(jbt4 = new JButton("4"));
    p1.add(jbt5 = new JButton("5"));
    p1.add(jbt6 = new JButton("6"));
    p1.add(jbtSub = new JButton("-"));
    p1.add(jbt7 = new JButton("7"));
    p1.add(jbt8 = new JButton("8"));
    p1.add(jbt9 = new JButton("9"));
    p1.add(jbtMul = new JButton("*"));
    p1.add(jbt0 = new JButton("0"));
    p1.add(jbtClear = new JButton("CE"));
    p1.add(jbtE = new JButton("="));
    p1.add(jbtDiv = new JButton("/"));

    JPanel p2 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    p2.add(jtfResult = new JTextField(8), BorderLayout.NORTH);
    p2.add(p1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    jtfResult.setEditable(false);

    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    this.add(p2, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    jbt1.addActionListener(new myListener());
    jbt2.addActionListener(new myListener());
    jbt3.addActionListener(new myListener());
    jbt4.addActionListener(new myListener());
    jbt5.addActionListener(new myListener());
    jbt6.addActionListener(new myListener());
    jbt7.addActionListener(new myListener());
    jbt8.addActionListener(new myListener());
    jbt9.addActionListener(new myListener());
    jbt0.addActionListener(new myListener());
    jbtAdd.addActionListener(new myListener());
    jbtDiv.addActionListener(new myListener());
    jbtSub.addActionListener(new myListener());
    jbtMul.addActionListener(new myListener());
    jbtE.addActionListener(new myListener());
    jbtClear.addActionListener(new myListener());

}

class myListener implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        String actionCommand = e.getActionCommand();
        if ("1".equals(actionCommand)){
        display = jtfResult.getText();
        jtfResult.setText(display + "1");
        }
        else if ("2".equals(actionCommand)){
        display = jtfResult.getText();
        jtfResult.setText(display + "2");
        }
        else if ("3".equals(actionCommand)){
        display = jtfResult.getText();
        jtfResult.setText(display + "3");
        }
        else if ("4".equals(actionCommand)){
        display = jtfResult.getText();
        jtfResult.setText(display + "4");
        }
        else if ("5".equals(actionCommand)){
        display = jtfResult.getText();
        jtfResult.setText(display + "5");
        }
        else if ("6".equals(actionCommand)){
        display = jtfResult.getText();
        jtfResult.setText(display + "6");
        }
        else if ("7".equals(actionCommand)){
        display = jtfResult.getText();
        jtfResult.setText(display + "7");
        }
        else if ("8".equals(actionCommand)){
        display = jtfResult.getText();
        jtfResult.setText(display + "8");
        }
        else if ("9".equals(actionCommand)){
        display = jtfResult.getText();
        jtfResult.setText(display + "9");
        }
        else if ("0".equals(actionCommand)){
        display = jtfResult.getText();
        jtfResult.setText(display + "0");
        }
        else if ("+".equals(actionCommand)){
        display1 = display;
        oper = '+';
        jtfResult.setText("");
        }
        else if ("-".equals(actionCommand)){
        oper = '-';
        display1 = display;
        jtfResult.setText("");
        }
        else if ("/".equals(actionCommand)){
        oper = '/';
        display1 = display;
        jtfResult.setText("");
        }
        else if ("*".equals(actionCommand)){
        oper = '*';
        display1 = display;
        jtfResult.setText("");
        }
        else if("=".equals(actionCommand)){
            solve();
            System.out.println(display1);
            System.out.println(display);
        }
        else if ("CE".equals(actionCommand)){
        jtfResult.setText("");
        }
    }//Action Performed
}

public void solve(){
number1 = Double.parseDouble(display1);
number2 = Double.parseDouble(display);
jtfResult.setText("");
if (oper == '+'){
    result = number1 + number2;
    String stringResult = Double.toString(result);
    jtfResult.setText(stringResult);
    }
else if (oper == '-'){
    result = number1 - number2;
    String stringResult = Double.toString(result);
    jtfResult.setText(stringResult);
    }
else if (oper == '*'){
    result = number1 * number2;
    String stringResult = Double.toString(result);
    jtfResult.setText(stringResult);
    }
else if (oper == '/'){
    if (number2 == 0)
        jtfResult.setText("ERROR");
    else    
    result = number1 / number2;
    String stringResult = Double.toString(result);
    jtfResult.setText(stringResult);    
    }
}

}
```

Comment: *"you will get a error."*  What error?  Always copy/paste error output rather than make us guess.  As an aside, don't forget to ask a question.

Comment: Place more println's in your code, especially before the location of errors. Then walk through your code logically as if you were the computer. Then you'll see that you don't change display (and by extension display1) like you think you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get current value from `jtfResult`.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        display = jtfResult.getText();  //<--------
        String actionCommand = e.getActionCommand();
        .....
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is here

```
display = jtfResult.getText();
jtfResult.setText(display + "1");
```

change it to

```
jtfResult.setText(display + "1");
display = jtfResult.getText();
```

Also whenever any operator is clicked you have to clear your display string.

On a side note, you should try to avoid writing duplicate code block, which ever solution you use to fix your issue you will be changing code so many places.

You can have your actionPerformed like this:

```
class myListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String actionCommand = e.getActionCommand();
        if ("=".equals(actionCommand)) {
            solve();
            System.out.println(display1);
            System.out.println(display);
        } else if ("CE".equals(actionCommand)) {
            jtfResult.setText("");
        } else {
            processInputReceived(actionCommand);
        }
    }// Action Performed
}
```

And your processInputReceived like

```
private void processInputReceived(String actionCommand){
    if(Character.isDigit(actionCommand.toCharArray()[0])){
        digitsSelected(actionCommand);
    } else {
        operatorSelected(actionCommand.toCharArray()[0]);
    }
}

private void operatorSelected(char selectedOperator){
    oper = selectedOperator;
    display1 = display;
    display = "";
    jtfResult.setText("");
}

private void digitsSelected(String selectedValue){
    jtfResult.setText(display + selectedValue);
    display = jtfResult.getText();
}
```